# Tour operator booking system for Joomla

Tags: reservation, booking

#### Requirements

I need help finding a Joomla extension for a self employed Tour Operator client to implement a booking system on his Joomla website as follows:

- a tour calendar (e.g. Day Tour A runs on Mon, Tue, Fri and Overnight
  Tour B on Sat/Sun)
- multiple pricing (e.g. different pricing on each tour and different pricing for adults, children, concessions)
- online booking and payment via direct deposit or PayPal
- capacity function where a particular tour might have six available seats so only 4 are available if 2 have already been booked
- a free or paid extension that can be implemented on the website is sought rather than integrating with an external online service such as [Rezdy](https://www.rezdy.com/) or similar as the client would like to avoid any additional monthly fees or commissions

#### Already tried: Event Booking

I have tried implementing custom fields in [Event Booking](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/calendars-a-events/events/event-booking) and installing the `plug_eventbooking_updatetotalregistrants.zip` plugin (found in the support forums) but this doesn't work well as the custom fields have to be applied to each tour individually which is onerous to maintain if you have more than one tour type and pricing is shown as "Free" on some pages when the Individual Price field is not being used:

[image: Event Booking]

#### Other extensions that have already been considered

Neither [JB Tour](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations/jb-tour) or [JE Tour](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations/je-tour) seem to satisfy the above requirements for various reasons.

Other suggestions are most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Suitable**

I am still looking but the most suitable I have found so far are:

**[Matukio Events](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/calendars-a-events/events/matukio-events)** from €59

Matukio Events seems to tick all the boxes and looks like the easiest to set up.

**[JEvents and RSVP Pro](http://jevents.net)** @ £62

JEvents and RSVP Pro can track capacity and handle adult/child/etc pricing but looks hard to configure.

**[Vik Events](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/calendars-a-events/events/vik-events)** @ €99

Vik Events seems to tick all the boxes but may be overkill for what is needed.

**[Appointment Booking Pro](http://appointmentbookingpro.com)** from $49

Appointment Booking Pro can track capacity and adult/child/senior pricing but does not have an intuitive calendar view.

**Unsuitable**

**[ohanah](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/calendars-a-events/events/ohanah)** can limit each ticket type (e.g. adult/child) but can't limit the total number of tickets.